# Android - Actualizar ArrayAdapter a partir de un nuevo array

Tags: java, android, json, listview, arrayadapter

necesito sabe como actualizar un ListView a partir de un ArrayAdapter propio por medio del array que le envio, me explico:
Tengo este JSON:

```
[{"id":"1","user":"117270122","mensaje":"Mensaje de prueba","condicion_visto":"0"},{"id":"2","user":"117270122","mensaje":"Mensaje","condicion_visto":"0"},{"id":"3","user":"117270122","mensaje":"Otro mensaje","condicion_visto":"0"}]
```

El cual lo extraigo de la base de datos y lo convierto en un ArrayList aqui:

```
public ArrayList<String> fillArray(){
    final ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
    Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                JSONArray nodo = new JSONArray(db.verificarDatosNuevos(user));//El JSON lo extraigo de la base de datos
                for (int i = 0; i < nodo.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json = nodo.getJSONObject(i);
                    String usuario = json.getString("user");
                    String mensaje = json.getString("mensaje");
                    String output = "Para: " + usuario + "\nMensaje: " + mensaje;
                    res.add(output);
                }
                System.out.println("NODO FINAL"+nodo.toString());
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("ARRAY FINAL"+res);
        }
    });
    th.start();
    try {
        th.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("ARRAY FINAL 2"+res);
    return res;
}
```

Mas adelante lo llamo en el OnCreate:

```
Adaptador ad = new Adaptador(Principal.this,R.layout.lista_mensajes,list,a);
ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.listaMensajes);
lv.setAdapter(ad);
```

El codigo de mi adaptador es el siguiente:

```
public class Adaptador extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    ArrayList<String> arr;
    private TextView text;
    private String usuario = "";
    JsonParser j;
    public Adaptador(Context context, int textViewResourceId,ArrayList<String> objects,String c){
        super(context,textViewResourceId,objects);
        this.arr = objects;
        System.out.println("CONSTRUCTOR: "+arr.size());
        this.usuario = c;
        this.j = new JsonParser(usuario);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        System.out.println("VIEW: "+arr.size());
        View view = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_mensajes,parent,false);
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textoMensaje);
        textView.setText(arr.get(position));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        return view;
    }

    public void actualizar(ArrayList<String> listaNueva){
        //this.arr.clear();
        this.arr = listaNueva;
        System.out.println("ACTUALIZAR: "+arr.toString());
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

El problema es que en un boton cuando llamo a la funcion actualizar, no se actualiza:

```
btnref.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            list = j.fillArray();
            ad.notifyDataSetChanged();
            ad.actualizar(list);
        }
    });
```

Cuando la base de datos cambia, el json cambia, pero no sé como hacer para que el adaptador lo reconozca y cambie la lista, o si habrá alguna otra manera de actualizar la lista?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder actualizar la lista, no puedes notificar un cambio de referencia en memoria de la misma, sino, modificar sus elementos.

En pocas palabras no puedes hacer: `this.lista = j.fillArray();`

El `Adapter` es poblado con una referencia. Al ser iniciado no puede cambiar la referencia de dicha lista y por eso al llamar notifyDataSetChanged no pasa nada. Lo que debes hacer es modificar la que ya tienes, **eliminando**, **agregando**, **limpiandola** o **insertando** elementos en ella. Si quieres cambiar uno o todos los elementos se utiliza `notifyDataSetChanged` por lo que deberías modificar tu lista de la siguiente manera:

```
btnref.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            list.clear(); // Limpia la lista anterior
            list.addAll(j.fillArray()); // agrega los nuevos elementos
            ad.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Basta con hacer eso para actualizar tu lista. Debes **eliminar** el método

> ```
> public void actualizar(ArrayList<String> listaNueva){
>         //this.arr.clear();
>         this.arr = listaNueva;
>         System.out.println("ACTUALIZAR: "+arr.toString());
>         this.notifyDataSetChanged();
>     }
> ```

y todas las demas llamadas a `notifyDataSetChanged();` que no sea la del `onClick`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, habia buscado todo el dia como actualizar la lista. Muy bien explicado

Comment: @DaylightArk ya te sirve de experiencia. Cualquier duda consulta y si no encuentras pues pregunta, aqui estamos. Buena suerte amigo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, precisamente me gusta investigar primero y resolverlo por mi mismo y solo preguntar a menos que sea necesario, y lo mas vacilon es que a veces son problemas tan pequeños que uno simplemente los pasa por alto.
De nuevo te agradezco mucho