# ¿Error en filtro de recyclerview (Android Studio)?

Tags: java, android-studio, filtro

sucede que tengo un proyecto en android studio el cual realiza una búsqueda en un recyclerview desde un searchview, al depurar mi aplicacion veo que si filtra bien los datos pero al mostrar los datos filtrados en el recyclerview muestra datos que no tienen que ver con la busqueda, aqui mi codigo

MainActivity

```html
public class InicioFragment extends Fragment {

    public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    public RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    public SearchView searchView;

    public Context context;
    public ArrayList<InicioItem> arrayList = new ArrayList<InicioItem>();
    public AppConfiguration appConfiguration;

    public List<Inicio> listCreditos;

    public InicioFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rclvInicio);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        searchView = (SearchView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.searchInicio);

        this.context = this.getContext();
        appConfiguration = (AppConfiguration) getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        arrayList = new ArrayList<InicioItem>();
      
        arrayList = GetArrayListInicioItem();
      
      adapter = new InicioRecyclerAdapter(context, arrayList);
      
      recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
             ((InicioRecyclerAdapter) adapter).getFilter().filter(newText.toString());
                return true;
            }
        });

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Adapter

```html
public class InicioRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InicioRecyclerAdapter.InicioRecyclerViewHolder> implements Filterable {
    ArrayList<InicioItem> arrayList = new ArrayList<InicioItem>();
    private static ArrayList<InicioItem> arrayListInicio = new ArrayList<InicioItem>();

    private ArrayList<InicioItem> inicioItemFilter;
    private ArrayList<InicioItem> filteredContactList;
    private CustomFilter mFilter;

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
   
    public InicioRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<InicioItem> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.arrayListInicio = arrayList;

        this.inicioItemFilter=arrayList;
        this.filteredContactList=new ArrayList<>();
        this.filteredContactList.addAll(arrayList);
        this.mFilter = new CustomFilter(InicioRecyclerAdapter.this);
       
    }
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return mFilter;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return filteredContactList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public InicioRecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_inicio_layout, parent, false);//LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()) --> inflate
        InicioRecyclerViewHolder inicioRecyclerViewHolder = new InicioRecyclerViewHolder(view);
        return inicioRecyclerViewHolder;
    }        

    
    //private class Filtro extends Filter{
    public class CustomFilter extends Filter {

        private InicioRecyclerAdapter inicioRecyclerAdapter;

        private CustomFilter(InicioRecyclerAdapter inicioRecyclerAdapter) {
            super();
            this.inicioRecyclerAdapter=inicioRecyclerAdapter;
        }

        @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                filteredContactList.clear();
                final FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            final String text = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                if (text != "" || text.length() != 0) {

                    for (final InicioItem item : inicioItemFilter) {
                        if (item.nombrePersona().toLowerCase().contains(text))
                           {
                            filteredContactList.add(item);
                    }

                    results.values = filteredContactList;
                    results.count = filteredContactList.size();
                }
                else
                {
                    filteredContactList.addAll(inicioItemFilter);
                }
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            this.inicioRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que *estas cambiando la referencia de una lista a otra*, no afectando sus elementos. El `RecyclerView` *ya tiene una referencia asignada, por lo tanto debes modificar la que ya esta*, no cambiarla.

En vez de hacer en el metodo `publishResults`:

```
inicioItemFilter = (ArrayList<InicioItem>) filterResults.values;
```

Debes hacer:

```
inicioItemFilter.clear(); // Limpiarla
inicioItemFilter.addAll((ArrayList<InicioItem>) filterResults.values); // Agregar todos los elementos del resultado
```

Si te sirve,  [revisa esta respuesta que hice hace un tiempo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/164729/38154).