# notifyDataSetChanged() no refresca los items de ListView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, json, api

Contexto: Estoy tratando de consumir una API, de donde recupero datos de clientes y con ellos pretendo crear un ListView.

Cabe resaltar que ya he comprobado que se reciben los datos.

### Clase cliente:

```
public class Cliente {
// Atributos
private int id, empleado_id;
private String nombre, telefono, email;

public Cliente(int id, int empleado_id, String nombre, String telefono, String email) {
    this.id = id;
    this.empleado_id = empleado_id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.telefono = telefono;
    this.email = email;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getEmpleado_id() {
    return empleado_id;
}

public void setEmpleado_id(int empleado_id) {
    this.empleado_id = empleado_id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getTelefono() {
    return telefono;
}

public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
    this.telefono = telefono;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
```

}

### Clase adaptador personalizado:

```
public class AdapterCliente extends ArrayAdapter<Cliente> {
// Atributos
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
JsonObjectRequest peticion;
private String url = "https://algunlugardelumundo/clientes/get_clientes.php";
private List<Cliente> clientes;

public AdapterCliente(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context, 0);

    // Crear nueva cola de peticiones
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    // Nueva petición JSONObject
    peticion = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            url,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    clientes = parseJson(response);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error respuesta en JSON: " + error.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    );

    // Añadir petición a la cola
    requestQueue.add(peticion);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View v, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater card = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if(v == null) {
        v = card.inflate(R.layout.card_cliente, parent, false);
    }
    TextView txtNombre = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
    Cliente cliente = getItem(position);
    txtNombre.setText(cliente.getNombre());
    return v;
}

public List<Cliente> parseJson(JSONObject jsonObject){
    // Variables locales
    List<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList();
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;

    try {
        // Obtener el array del objeto
        jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("clientes");

        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            try {
                JSONObject objeto = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                Cliente cliente = new Cliente(objeto.getInt("id"),
                        objeto.getInt("empleado_id"),
                        objeto.getString("nombre"),
                        objeto.getString("telefono"),
                        objeto.getString("email")
                );

                clientes.add(cliente);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error de parsing: " + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return clientes;
}
```

}

### ListaClientes:

```
public class ListaClientes extends AppCompatActivity {
// Atributos
ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_clientes);
    // Obtener instancia de la lista
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvClientes);

    // Crear y setear adaptador
    adapter = new AdapterCliente(this);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Android - Actualizar ArrayAdapter a partir de un nuevo array](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164727/android-actualizar-arrayadapter-a-partir-de-un-nuevo-array)

Answer (score 1):

Move el `notifySetDataChanged()` de aca

```
new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    clientes = parseJson(response);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
```

Al metodo parseJson luego de añadirlo al array

```
try {
                JSONObject objeto = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                Cliente cliente = new Cliente(objeto.getInt("id"),
                        objeto.getInt("empleado_id"),
                        objeto.getString("nombre"),
                        objeto.getString("telefono"),
                        objeto.getString("email")
                );

                clientes.add(cliente);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error de parsing: " + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Lo que pasa es que estas notificando al adaptador por cambios antes que se pueblen en el array.